# Drop down background url in Safari Issue

Tags: css, safari

```
selectBox.selectCSS
    {
        background: url(/Images/replacementSelectBackground.png) top left no-repeat height:auto;
    }
```

I have an issue in Safari only where the image is not rendering on top of the drop down list.

It will only work if I remove the height:auto attribute, but then it won't work in Chrome.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't compute. There's no element called `selectBox` in HTML. Is this some custom XML you're applying the CSS to, or is it supposed to be HTML? If so, the HTML element name for a "drop down" is `select`. You're also missing a semicolon (`;`) between `no-repeat` and `height` to separate the two property assignments. I guess that syntax error is what's causing the problem in Safari.